# Whenever I try to reach saddahaq.com I am getting a Server Not Found issue. Everyone except me is able to reach that website

Tags: google-chrome

I am using Ubuntu OS and Google Chrome browser - Version 44.0.2403.157 (64-bit). i searched for the solution, i tried these

check the website is blocked in hosts : /etc/hosts
its clear nothing wrong

[image: Check the Image]

nslookup command - 
[image: Check the image]

is there anything left from my side to check and resolve this issue.

i used proxy on firefox, its working but very slow.

Please help me to resolve this issue

Comment: Don't post screenshots of text. Just copy paste it here.

Comment: Did you got my problem